# One-liner to sort STRUCT in MATLAB?

Tags: sorting, matlab

Seeking a one-liner MATLAB function / command to sort by date the output of:

```
filenames = dir(filenameSubstring);  % retruns struct
```

**sortrows()** is for matrices and seems to rely on the sorting column to be a number.

Seeking to avoid re-inventing the wheel and using MATLAB's stock capability.  If a one-liner is not possible, then concise solutions are appreciated.

## UPDATE

Two-Liner per first comment in [Mathworks blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/09/17/sorting-structure-arrays-based-on-fields/):

```
%% Sort the struct by file save date
[tmp ind]=sort({filenames.date});
filenames=filenames(ind);
```

Answer (score 2):

Making a solution work is the first step. The solution in your post works only if all dates are from the same month and year.

***Example:***

If you have these dates:

```
'18-May-2017 01:01:36'
'18-Jun-2018 22:58:50'
'19-Jun-2018 01:52:32'
```

your code arranges them as:

```
'18-Jun-2018 22:58:50'
'18-May-2017 01:01:36'
'19-Jun-2018 01:52:32'
```

which is clearly wrong.

Your code can be fixed using [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) (introduced in R2014b) as follows:

```
[~, ind] = sort(datetime({filenames.date}));
filenames = filenames(ind);
```

---

One-liners are overrated. Any approach to make it one-liner is very likely to be worse than the above elegant approach. If you just want to write it in one line then write it in one line as:

```
[~, ind] = sort(datetime({filenames.date}));  filenames = filenames(ind);
```

or create a function that does that and call that function i.e.

```
function filenames = sortbydate(filenames)
[~, ind] = sort(datetime({filenames.date}));
filenames = filenames(ind);
end
```

and call this function with:

```
filenames = sortbydate(filenames);
```

Comment: Good observation.